# Computer doesn't turn on

Tags: boot, desktop-computer

community!

Recently, I got this computer fixed at a local computer store in my city because the hard drive wasn't working correctly. The computer worked fine for like 2 weeks and then it suddenly froze with a lot of lines appear on the screen. I thinked this was an overheating issue but the computer was just on the desktop copying files between USB Drives. It was running Windows XP SP3 because the computer was older.
When I went to turn back on the computer, the green power LED won't come on, only the HDD LED will stay lit up without the power led. The computer doesn't turn on no matter what. I also tried a different PSU but that did no good. What could be the problem?

Also, another note: When I hit the power button, I hear the HDD spin up. When turned on, the computer restarts once then stays on. Yes, I removed all peripherals including the monitor at one point. I don't have any PCI cards installed, Yes, I tried reseating cpu, and the ram in a different slot. Yes, I tried booting the PC without the HDD in. Same problem.

Specs:

*Motherboard*: VIA K8M800-8237

*CPU*: AMD Sempron 3000+

*RAM*: Hyundai 1x512MB Stick

Comment: Take it back to the repair shop.

Comment: If the computer is too old, it might not be worth another repair.